# playframework scala code efficiency and future problems

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

Hi I have the following code block

```
processSteps.map {
          step =>
            val prerequisiteFuture = processStepPrerequisitesDTO.getProcessStepPrerequisiteProcessTemplateIds(step.id.get)
            prerequisiteFuture.map(prereqTemplates => {
              processTemplateDTO.getProcessTemplates(prereqTemplates).map(pres => {
                step.stepPrerequisites = Some(pres)
                // Fetches the ProcessStep Prerequisites
                processStepPrerequisitesDTO.getProcessStepPrerequisitesByProcessTemplateId(step.id.get).map(processStepPrerequisites => {
                  processStepPrerequisites.map(processStepPrerequisite => { // Eintzelne Vorbedingung
                    // Feteches The Reference to the Process Step Prerequisite Template
                    processStepPrerequisitesDTO.getProcessStepsPrerequisiteProcessTemplate(step.id.get).map(preReqs => {
                      preReqs.foreach(preReqRelation => {
                        processStepPrerequisite.processTemplate_id = preReqRelation.processtemplate
                        processStepPrerequisite
                      })
                    })
                    processStepPrerequisites
                  })
                  step.prerequisites = Some(processStepPrerequisites)
                })
                step
              })
            })
```

I want to fetch some data from database and then I have to reorganisate the some data.

It works ... but not well

Problems are:

1) Code is not efficient
2) Often it returns the step at the and without the middple part with the `processStepPrerequisite` is finished

What would be a good and smart way to resolve this? thanks

[image]

Comment: The code would gain "a lot" in readability using for comprehension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a for comprehension for doing your stuff in the following way:

```
val preReqFuture = for{
    step <- processSteps
    prereqTemplates <- processStepPrerequisitesDTO.getProcessStepPrerequisiteProcessTemplateIds(step.id.get)
    pres <- processTemplateDTO.getProcessTemplates(prereqTemplates)
    processStepPrerequisites <-processStepPrerequisitesDTO.getProcessStepPrerequisitesByProcessTemplateId(step.id.get)
    preReqs <- processStepPrerequisitesDTO.getProcessStepsPrerequisiteProcessTemplate(step.id.get)
} yield (step, pres, processStepPrerequisites, preReqs)

preReqFuture.map{ (step, pres, processStepPrerequisites, preReqs) => 
    processStepPrerequisites.map(processStepPrerequisite => {
        preReqs.foreach(preReqRelation => { 
            processStepPrerequisite.processTemplate_id = preReqRelation.processtemplate
            processStepPrerequisite
        })
    })
    step.stepPrerequisites = Some(pres)
    step.prerequisites = Some(processStepPrerequisites)
    step
}.recover {
    case error: Throwable => //Deal with error
}
```

**Note: I have assumed that processSteps is also a Future.**

Comment: the above postet snippet is in a Future.sequence()
When I copy your codeI got lots of errors

Comment: is processSteps a future?

Comment: can u post the errors? I can't help without seeing the errors.

Comment: `found   : scala.concurrent.Future[(models.ProcessStepTemplatesModel, Seq[models.ProcessTemplatesModel], Seq[models.ProcessStepPrerequisitesModel], Seq[models.ProcessStepPrerequisiteProcessTemplateModel])]
`

Comment: `required: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]
[error]           prereqTemplates <- processStepPrerequisitesDTO.getProcessStepPrerequisiteProcessTemplateIds(step.id.get)
`

Comment: also added a screenshot above

Answer (score 1):

If you want, `step` to be returned when all the actions are finished, just return it in the last `map` block.

For the efficiency of your code, the problem is probably not in the snippet that you have provided but in the `processStepPrerequisitesDTO` methods.

Comment: Tried this, but did not change the behaviour. 

In the DTOs I have only database calls with slick